# Getting the file counts for more than one multiple-file-input field

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a page where people can upload multiple photos at once to make into a slideshow. Now, I already have the code to get multiple files:

```
<input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" id="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" size="20" />
```

And the code to count how many photos were actually selected in the form:

```
alert(document.getElementById('filesToUpload').files.length);
```

The problem lies when the user actually wants to make multiple slideshows. If so, I cannot anymore use the code above, but still need to keep the inputs have only one Name so the PHP file that actually uploads the files could stay simple.

If I do use the code above, what happens is only the first fileinput field would be counted.

Is there actually a way to count several fileinput fields with the same Name?

Comment: You can't give to elements the same id, because id are unique. And I don't know what PHP is doing with ids. Generally the keys for user inputs come from the `name` attribute. And this key for `$_POST`, `$_GET` or `$_FILE` should also be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there actually a way to count several fileinput fields with the
>   same ID?

`id` of element in `document` should be unique. Substitute `class` for `id`.

You can use `.querySelectorAll(".filesToUpload")` to a `NodeList` of each `".filesToUpload"`  element, pass to result to `Array.from()` to create an array from the `NodeList`, iterate the array and return an object where the index of the element within `NodeList` and `.files` `.length` are properties of a returned object.

You can also use `.reduce()` to get the total number of uploaded files from the array returned from `.map()`.

```html
<form>
  <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" class="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" size="20" />
  <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" class="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" size="20" />
  <input type="file" name="filesToUpload[]" class="filesToUpload" multiple="multiple" size="20" /><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
<script>
  const inputs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".filesToUpload"));
  const form = document.forms[0];
  form.onsubmit = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    
    let fileIndexes = inputs.map(function(input, index) {
      return {files: input.files.length, filesToUploadIndex: index}
    });
    
    let filesTotal = {filesTotal:fileIndexes.reduce(function(a, b) {
      return a + b.files
    }, 0)};
    
    console.log(fileIndexes, filesTotal)
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is ingenious. Thank you!
This not only solved my problem, but also taught something new. Really, thank you! 

But, since I'm not really too keen in using this language yet, is there a way to turn what was outputted in the console into an array I can manipulate in Javascript?

Comment: `fileIndexes` is an array

Comment: Aye, but whenever I print it I get [object Object],[object Object],[object Object]. 
What am I missing? There a way for the array to contain only the numbers I need?

Comment: Return `input.files.length` from `.map()`. What do you mean by "print it"?

Comment: I am incredibly thankful you are taking the time to answer my questions.
Ahh. For example I use the code you sent and upload 4, 5, and 6 files in the three file inputs. 
Is there a way to get an array that only has {4,5,6} in it?

And by print it, I meant I put in in an alert, instead of console.log.
So I got the [object Object],[object Object],[object Object].

Comment: `let fileIndexes = inputs.map(function(input, index) {
      return  input.files.length
    })`, `alert(JSON.stringify(fileIndexes))`

Comment: Thank you very much. :) I'll just experiment with this now, but you have been incredibly helpful. Thank you.

Comment: @MarlXtianMonzonMarcera Does Answer resolve original Question?

Comment: Yes it does, I can just add a bit more code to insert that into a hidden element in the document to send it via form to the Server. :)

Comment: My bad, I just realized something big. I made a mistake in my question. What I actually meant was "Elements with the same name" instead of ID. 
Since HTML actually accepts that, but not Elements with the same ID.